# create a game like crosswords in Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a game like crosswords, which will have a drag and drop, zoom functionality . Can somebody direct me how can I proceed for this? Is there any 3rd party Jar needed to develop?

Which view is perfect for this, I mean, to create a chess board like UI and letters on top of it.

I need to drag one letter from 1 column to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are somany engines available for game developing they easily support drag and drop functionality.check this engines like

Andengine,libgdx,cocos2d try using these engines

Comment: Thanks..I decided to go with cocos2d. Not sure I can achieve it.. will check it and let you know